# The multi-part identifier can not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this request

```
    SELECT ACC.ID_LIENPARENTE,
        ACC.ID_VOYAGE,
        ACC.LI_ACC_NOM,
        ACC.LI_ACC_PRENOM,
        ACC.PA_ID_INDICATIF_TEL,
        ACC.CO_ACC_MEL,
        ACC.TE_ACC_TELEPHONE,
        E_PAYS.PA_ID AS PA_ID_INDICATIF_TEL_ACC, 
        E_PAYS.PA_I_INDICATIF AS PA_INDICATIF_TEL_ACC, 
        E_PAYS.PA_L_NOM_LISTE as PA_L_NOM_LISTE_INDICATIF_TEL_ACC
    FROM
    dbo.E_ACCOMPAGNANT ACC
    JOIN E_PAYS ON E_ACCOMPAGNANT.PA_ID_INDICATIF_TEL = E_PAYS.PA_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.R_LIEN_PARENTE LIEN_PAR
    ON
    ACC.ID_LIENPARENTE = LIEN_PAR.ID_LIENPARENTE
    WHERE ID_VOYAGE = 10
```

when i execute this i have this error message:

> The multi-part identifier " E_ACCOMPAGNANT.PA_ID_INDICATIF_TEL " can
>   not be bound.

What is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define an alias name for a table, then you have to use it **always**.
Replace

```
JOIN E_PAYS ON E_ACCOMPAGNANT.PA_ID_INDICATIF_TEL = E_PAYS.PA_ID
```

with

```
JOIN E_PAYS ON ACC.PA_ID_INDICATIF_TEL = E_PAYS.PA_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to reference  `PA_ID_INDICATIF_TEL` by the alias `ACC`

```
 SELECT ACC.ID_LIENPARENTE,
        ACC.ID_VOYAGE,
        ACC.LI_ACC_NOM,
        ACC.LI_ACC_PRENOM,
        ACC.PA_ID_INDICATIF_TEL,
        ACC.CO_ACC_MEL,
        ACC.TE_ACC_TELEPHONE,
        E_PAYS.PA_ID AS PA_ID_INDICATIF_TEL_ACC, 
        E_PAYS.PA_I_INDICATIF AS PA_INDICATIF_TEL_ACC, 
        E_PAYS.PA_L_NOM_LISTE as PA_L_NOM_LISTE_INDICATIF_TEL_ACC
    FROM
    dbo.E_ACCOMPAGNANT ACC
    JOIN E_PAYS ON ACC.PA_ID_INDICATIF_TEL = E_PAYS.PA_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.R_LIEN_PARENTE LIEN_PAR
    ON
    ACC.ID_LIENPARENTE = LIEN_PAR.ID_LIENPARENTE
    WHERE ID_VOYAGE = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by `juergen` you need to use the `alias` name if you are joining the tables.

Here you go

```
  SELECT ACC.ID_LIENPARENTE,
    ACC.ID_VOYAGE,
    ACC.LI_ACC_NOM,
    ACC.LI_ACC_PRENOM,
    ACC.PA_ID_INDICATIF_TEL,
    ACC.CO_ACC_MEL,
    ACC.TE_ACC_TELEPHONE,
    E_PAYS.PA_ID AS PA_ID_INDICATIF_TEL_ACC, 
    E_PAYS.PA_I_INDICATIF AS PA_INDICATIF_TEL_ACC, 
    E_PAYS.PA_L_NOM_LISTE as PA_L_NOM_LISTE_INDICATIF_TEL_ACC
FROM
dbo.E_ACCOMPAGNANT ACC
--JOIN E_PAYS ON E_ACCOMPAGNANT.PA_ID_INDICATIF_TEL = E_PAYS.PA_ID // alias not used
JOIN E_PAYS ON ACC.PA_ID_INDICATIF_TEL = E_PAYS.PA_ID  -- need to use alias for query
INNER JOIN dbo.R_LIEN_PARENTE LIEN_PAR
ON
ACC.ID_LIENPARENTE = LIEN_PAR.ID_LIENPARENTE
WHERE ID_VOYAGE = 10
```